# current_app and importing config settings in Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Recently, I've started building an app with Flask. It's pretty easy to use, yet powerful and fun to use. Unfortunately, I'm having problems understanding how the app context works. I know about `current_app`, `app_context` and that `current_app` references are supposed to be used inside requests, but that's probably part of my problem.

I'm building an app with the following folder structure:

```
app/
     main/
         __init__.py
         error.py
         forms.py
         routes.py
     static/
     templates/
     __init__.py
     email.py
     models.py
config.py
run.py
```

I'm doing an `from flask import current_app` in `routes.py` to import config settings and it works as expected.

But when I import current_app in `forms.py` I can do whatever I want, but I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app('development')
  File "/home/letmecode/Projects/python/flask/folder/app/__init__.py", line 34, in create_app
    from main import main as main_blueprint
  File "/home/letmecode/Projects/python/flask/folder/app/main/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import routes, errors, forms
  File "/home/letmecode/Projects/python/flask/folder/app/main/routes.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import (ChangePasswordForm, ChangeEmailForm, CreateItemForm, RetrievePasswordForm, LoginForm,
  File "/home/letmecode/Projects/python/flask/folder/app/main/forms.py", line 132, in <module>
    class CreateItemForm(Form):
  File "/home/letmecode/Projects/python/flask/folder/app/main/forms.py", line 133, in CreateItemForm
    print current_app
  File "/home/letmecode/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 362, in <lambda>
    __str__ = lambda x: str(x._get_current_object())
  File "/home/letmecode/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/letmecode/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

`forms.py` is just a module that contains flask-wtf form classes and validator functions.

My problem is, that I want to reference the app context inside there, in order to get settings that are used throughout the app.

What am I doing wrong here? I guess what happens inside `forms.py` is not part of a request and therefore fails somehow. But how else am I supposed to reference the app context, then?

**Edit:**

```
#forms.py

from flask import current_app

#[...]

class CreateItemForm(Form):
    title = TextField('Title', [
        validators.Length(min=3, max=140),
        validators.Regexp('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$', 0, 'Item titles must start with a letter and consist of numbers and letters, only')
    ])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', [
        validators.Length(min=3, max=1000),
    ])
    tags = TextField('Tags')
    branch = SelectField(
        'Branch',
        choices=current_app.config['BRANCHES']
    )
```

Comment: please post your CreateItemForm class ... basically move the current_app into a method of that instead of at the class level

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I forgot that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying issue is that `CreateItemForm` and all of the attributes are created when the `forms` module is imported for the first time.  That means that the `branch` field is created whenever `import .form` is run, and therefore `current_app` is accessed then:

```
# app/main/routes.py
from .forms import ( ..., CreateItemForm, ...)
```

Looking at your stack trace, this happens in your `create_app` call - most likely, your `create_app` looks something like this:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask('some-name-here')
    app.config.from_SOMETHING(config_name)

    # Register things here
    from main import main as main_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(...)

    return app
```

At `# Register things here` you can simply create an `app_context` and import everything inside of that:

```
# Register things here
# Creating an explicit application context to allow
# easy access to current_app.config, etc.
with app.app_context():
    from main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(...)

return app
```

Comment: That's it! I've completely misunderstood how `app_context` works and used it wrongly, that's why I didn't get it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was being an idiot. You don't have to provide choices per form model. You can (and should) provide them via the view/route function e.g.:

```
form.select_field.choices = [('value1', 'label1'), ('value2', 'label2')]
```

This doesn't explicitly answer my question, but renders it somewhat obsolete. However, I won't accept my own answer as a solution (yet), because I am curious as to whether it's at all possible to import configuration options from via app/current_app in this case, without getting hacky. If my curiosity won't be satisfied, I'll accept my own answer.

I wish the wtforms/flask-wtf documentation would focus less on the obvious and more on the not so obvious.